# Read Jenkins log in shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement that I need to parse the Jenkins job after the completion to grep out the error log and send it in email to the team. Could someone of you suggest what plugin/option is available in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse out the console output after the build steps, try using [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

You can use the `manager.logContains` function or the `manager.build.logFile` variable to get the console output.